# Using Pyspark to read in Elasticsearch Data to Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, pyspark

I am trying to use the Python ElasticSearch library to read in elasticsearch documents and place them in a spark dataframe. I am able to connect and query using the `scan` helper function since the query will generate about 2M documents(rows in my dataframe). The issue I am running into is getting the query into a spark dataframe.

This code produces a generator:

```
result = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(es, index=index, doc_type='_doc', query=query)
```

I was trying to use a for loop to fill a to collect the generated data into a dictionary:

```
data = {}
for item in result:
  data.append((item['_source']['someField'], item['_source']['someField']))
return data
```

but I run into errors as I do not think a dictionary can append in this way.

Is there a better way to collect this generated data into a spark dataframe?
Note:I am also working on the Databricks platform if that helps.

Comment: What is the error that you got ?

Comment: Dict doesn't support append when I try the for.loop.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162901/how-to-query-an-elasticsearch-index-using-pyspark-and-dataframes