# Spark error class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following error when I tried to get data from elasticsearch by spark. The error don't specify where is the error.

The body2 works in dev tools in elasticsearch

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

body2={
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "lte": "2022-05-03T09:25:15.000-03:00",
                            "gte": "2022-05-04T09:25:15.000-03:00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "type.keyword": "TABLA"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size":10
}



es_read_conf = {
    "es.nodes": "10.45.15.93",
    "es.port": "9200",
    "es.query": body2,
    "es.nodes.wan.only": "true",
    "es.resource" : "indice1/TABLA",
    "es.net.http.auth.user": "usuario1", 
    "es.net.http.auth.pass": "rsl242442j"
}

es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", 
    conf=es_read_conf)
```

Here is the error and I don´t know where is the error in the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 859, in newAPIHadoopRDD
    jrdd = self._jvm.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(self._jsc, inputFormatClass, keyClass,
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.HashMap and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonHadoopUtil$.$anonfun$mapToConf$1(PythonHadoopUtil.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonHadoopUtil$.$anonfun$mapToConf$1$adapted(PythonHadoopUtil.scala:160)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
```

...

I review the code and I'dont get the solution

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message describes, the problem is that query should be a string and not a dictionary:

```py
body2="""{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                            "lte": "2022-05-03T09:25:15.000-03:00",
                            "gte": "2022-05-04T09:25:15.000-03:00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "type.keyword": "TABLA"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size":10
}"""
```

You can see a reference for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162901/how-to-query-an-elasticsearch-index-using-pyspark-and-dataframes)